# CGI: Redirecting STDERR to file with an alteration

Tags: perl

Redirecting `STDERR` to an external file is pretty easy

```
my $stderr = '/home/logs/stderr.log.txt';
open STDERR, '>' . $stderr;
...
$_ = 1/0; # Error: Illegal division by zero
```

To make this error log file more readable I want to **prepend** a timestamp information each time sometimes is sent to `STDERR`.

How can be that accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way without too many disruptions to the rest of your code is to use tied filehandles. Tied filehandles allow you to write customized functions that are invoked when your filehandle is read from, written to, or has any other operation performed on it.

Proof-of-concept

```
package TimeStamper;
sub TIEHANDLE {
   my ($pkg,$file) = @_;
   open my $fh, ">", $file;  # the "real" filehandle
   return bless [$fh],$pkg;
}
sub PRINT {
   my ($self,@msg) = @_;
   print {$self->[0]} "[",scalar localtime,"] ",@msg;
}

package main;
my $stderr = "/home/logs/stderr.log.txt";
tie *STDERR, "TimeStamper", $stderr;

print STDERR "Hello world\n";
```

Comment: The one caveat is this won't affect any external code that prints to STDERR such as C libraries.